# JSON Schema - Instance has no additional fields other than the ones declared in the schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to validate that a specific JSON instance has no additional fields outside of the ones declared in the schema.

Let s take this schema as an example:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Client",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "isActive": {
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    },
    "required": []
}
```

I would like to enforce that any JSON of this "type" can only have name, email and isActive. If the following JSON is validated I would like validation to fail:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "email": "john@example.com",
   "isActive": true,
   "extrafield": 123
}
```

I am using [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) to execute the validation, but I have a feeling that more than an implementation issue/assumption with the specific validator I am using, it is my JSON schema that is not enforcing preventing undefined fields.

How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `additionalProperties`.

> The value of "additionalProperties" MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> This keyword determines how child instances validate for objects,
> and    does not directly validate the immediate instance itself.
>
> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
> values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
> and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".
>
> For all such properties, validation succeeds if the child instance
> validates against the "additionalProperties" schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6

To translate: The value of a key in `properties`, which is a schema, is applied to the object of the instance of the keys value.

Any properties of your instance object which are not validated by `properties` (nor by `patternProperties`), are then evaluated by `additionalProperties`.

The value of any schema can be `false`, which assers validation failure, so you want to add `additionalProperties: false` to your schema.

Note however, that `additionalProperties` cannot "see through" other applicator keywords like `oneOf`, and is only applicable based on `properties` and `patternProperties`.

(draft-8 will introduce a new key word, `unevaluatedProperties` to provide this functionality, but that version is not published at current).

Comment: Excellent! That is enough for my use case. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Super, I'm glad it made sense! I was a little worried the language used might be confusing, but with JSON Schema, applicability is important to understand =]